# How to use a library which contains an activity in my own fragment?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm doing some UI work in my Android project. Recently, I found a really cool library named `Euclid` on GitHub, but I met problems when using it.

The library is an `Activity` extended from `Activity`:

```
public abstract class EuclidActivity extends Activity {
    ........
}
```

and in the sample, this is how the author uses his library:

```
public class MainActivity extends EuclidActivity {
    ......
}
```

but for me, I have a `MainActivity` with 3 fragments, so this is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 ......
}
```

so  I can't extend `EuclidActivity`.

I'm thinking of adding some code in `HomepageFragment`, but I don't know how.

Any tips?

Comment: I guess `EuclidActivity` from the library should allow you to override how the UI look and feel should be (if it isn't , it might be poorly designed or it serves a single purpose). Can you put a link to the library

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/Yalantis/Euclid)
here it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extends EuclidActivity and can load fragments inside that.

Note: FragmentActivity is a special activity provided in the Support Library to handle fragments on system versions older than API level 11. If the lowest system version you support is API level 11 or higher, then you can use a regular Activity.

check this doc : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout

Comment: thank sincerely first!

Yes I've tried to change
`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`
to
`public class MainActivity extends EuclidActivity`
but after finishing that 
the line :
`fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); ` shows error:
can"t resolve method........

Comment: you should change to  - `fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Yes I did ,But then I get the error :
`fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content,homepageFragment);`  
-->Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.ye.deertutor.Fragments.HomepageFragment)'  (deertutor is my project's name)
is there something wrong of the parameter? and how can I fix it?
thank you sincerely!

Comment: change your fragment import v4.fragment to fragment

Comment: thank you very much for your tip ! and I've gladly solved my problem ,this is how I did : I changed :
`public class HomepageFragment extends Fragment`  to 
`public class HomepageFragment extends android.app.Fragment`